# What periodic timer objects are available in the Windows API?

Tags: winapi, timer

In researching options for getting better than the 15 ms resolution provided by .NET timer objects (see [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3744032/why-are-net-timers-limited-to-15-ms-resolution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3744032/why-are-net-timers-limited-to-15-ms-resolution-)), I am looking at the different timer objects that Windows provides.  I have identified the following:

- [Old style Windows timer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms632592(v=VS.85).aspx)
- [Multimedia timers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd743609(v=VS.85).aspx)
- [Waitable timer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms687012(v=VS.85).aspx)
- [Timer queue timers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms686796(v=VS.85).aspx)
- [Threadpool timers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682466(v=VS.85).aspx)

Are there other timer types available in the Windows API?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I asked this question because I was interested in implementing a periodic timer that would give me better granularity than the timers that are supplied with .NET.  My investigation of those timers (`Windows.Forms.Timer`, `System.Timers.Timer`, and `System.Threading.Timer`) shows that the best I can hope for is 15 ms granularity, and accuracy of -1 to +30 ms.  That's fine for most applications, but not for the application I was working on.

For details of my investigation, see [Why are .NET timers limited to 15 ms resolution?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3744032/why-are-net-timers-limited-to-15-ms-resolution) and http://www.informit.com/guides/content.aspx?g=dotnet&seqNum=815.

That led me to looking for periodic timer objects available under Windows.  I identified the five types that I posted in the original question.  I didn't find any others.  I discarded the old-style Windows timer because I don't want to be processing messages.  I then wrote managed prototypes in C# for the other four timer types and did some testing.

All four timer types (Multimedia timers, Waitable timers, Timer queue timers, and Threadpool timers) give a reliable 1 ms interval, with very good resolution.  Of those, the Threadpool timer is by far the easiest to interact with, but unfortunately it's not supported on Windows XP.  Timer queue timers have a dizzying array of options, but if you ignore most of the options they're almost as simple as Threadpool timers.  See [Exploring options for better timers](http://www.informit.com/guides/content.aspx?g=dotnet&seqNum=816) for more info.

I chose to wrap the timer queue timer for my general timer class in .NET.  You can see it [here](http://www.informit.com/guides/content.aspx?g=dotnet&seqNum=817).

You might also be interested in [Waitable Timers in .NET with C#](http://www.devsource.com/c/a/Languages/Waitable-Timers-in-NET-CSharp/).