# Time for a command to be executed

Tags: c#, multithreading, timer

I am connecting with an instrument using the following command.

```
instrument = programmer.GetInstrument(_address);
```

I want to know how long it takes for this command to be executed.

Comment: Can you give more details as to why a stopwatch will not work in your case?

Comment: I need this to be deterministic and want to make sure I am only tracking the time to execute this command.  At least this is what I am told.  I am going to run it with a simple timer a few times and post the results soon.

Comment: `I am going to run it with a simple timer a few times and post the results soon.` You asked this question before trying it ?

Comment: @Eser I have already tried it but always get the same results which does not make sense in the context that it is executed.  Stop flagging me with negative comments.I said I will try it a few more times...

Comment: `Stop flagging me with negative comments.`  I though I can vote freely here. If you don't like it try to ask better questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want to do an in-line thread, you could do this code:

```
System.Threading.Thread t = new System.Threading.Thread(delegate()
{
    try
    {
        DateTime cmdStartTime = DateTime.UtcNow;
        instrument = programmer.GetInstrument(_address);
        DateTime cmdEndTime = DateTime.UtcNow;

        TimeSpan totalCmdRuntime = cmdEndTime - cmdStartTime;
        Debug.WriteLine(String.Format("Programmer.GetInstrument({0}) command took {1} mSec to execute", _address, totalCmdRuntime.TotalMilliseconds));
    }
    catch { }
});
t.Name = "GetInstrumentTimer";
t.Start();
```

Comment: this should do it.  I will try it right now and find out if this makes a difference in my timing.

Comment: This is essentially the same as using a stopwatch, but with much lesser precision, which may not be good for your use case.

Comment: Yes.  It is likely your command is executing faster than the resolution of the timer you are using.   See SO http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3744032/why-are-net-timers-limited-to-15-ms-resolution for some alternatives.