# How costly is it to fetch DateTime.UtcNow in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, datetime, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a method which is going to be called a few 100 times on one call and I have a choice how I want to call the `DateTime.UtcNow`:

- Ask for `DateTime.UtcNow` inside the method and the `DateTime.UtcNow` is fetched each time; or
- Give `DateTime.UtcNow` as a parameter to the method and it is only fetched once (but the `DateTime` value saved will be a few milliseconds apart for every entry saved, but thats fine).

Now this question has an obvious answer, but now I'm curious:  how costly is it to fetch the `DateTime.UtcNow`?

Comment: You could benchmark it using Benchmark.NET.

Comment: [Race your horses](https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`DateTime.UtcNow` involves a bit of work and a native call, so it's not completely trivial.

However, you're doing I/O. Regardless of the kind of I/O you're doing, any `DateTime.UtcNow` calls are going to be completely dwarfed by the I/O. A simple test with debug build and no compiler optimizations on my computer (with my version of the runtime, my version of Windows etc. etc.) shows that I can make seven million `DateTime.UtcNow` calls per second. It doesn't even use any CPU. There's not much else you can do *with* the `DateTime` object that's going to be appreciably faster. Do you save it in the database? That's orders of magnitude slower. Do you save it in a file? Again, orders of magnitude slower. Do you send it back to the client? Again, orders of magnitude slower.

So, unless you need to call `DateTime.UtcNow` a hundred thousand times during the request, focus on making the code easy to understand. That may mean storing `DateTime.UtcNow` in a local, or passing it around in a field or through method arguments; or it may mean calling `DateTime.UtcNow` whenever you want. Maybe you even want to always have the same time during the same request - that's all in your design.

Don't worry about the performance until you actually have a reason to worry.

Answer (score 2):

By default, the system clock only updates once every 15ms anyways, so there's no advantage to checking the time over and over in your method.  More info on timer resolution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3744104/794234).

As for the efficiency of the method itself - [check the reference source](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/datetime.cs,1069).  It makes a single call to the CLR to get the file time.  The rest of it is high speed ops on an optimized `struct`.  It's unlikely that takes any significant amount of time.

Comment: In my system (AMD Athlon, Win10) the clock updates every 1ms.