# Why is Node.js performance on Windows server significantly improved by running VSCode at the same time?

Tags: node.js

EDIT: Although I have not found an answer to the question, I have found a solution to the problem: use `setImmediate()` instead of `setTimeout()`. This has really speeded up execution without impacting the web server responsiveness. But the mystery of the behaviour of `setTimeout()` still remains unanswered, at least for now.

---

This is a Node.js performance question that is quite baffling to me.

I have set up a node.js web server application running on Windows 2012 R2, using only the built-in Node http library. I am not using any other Node libraries. To develop the app I use Remote Desktop Connection to log on to the server from a separate workstation on the same 1GB LAN, and then use Visual Studio Code on the server to edit the Node.js source code. The web server is run through a separate cmd window, using `>node webserver.js`

Apart from being a web server, the main purpose of the app is to carry out continuous calculations over many hours. The calculations are quite simple, but tedious, and are done in batches of around 2000, using a loop implemented by calling `setTimeout( cycle_function, 1 )` at the end of each cycle, to fire up the next cycle. The loop is set up like this simply to allow the app to respond to incoming http requests without locking up.

Each execution of the cycle is called a tick, and a tick counter is maintained. A separate interval timer of 1000ms is set to run a small function that records how many cycles of calculations (ticks) were performed in the previous second, i.e. ticks per second. It does this by recording the tick count, and calculating the difference between the previous tick count and the current tick count each time it is run.

The up-to-date results of the calculations done so far can be viewed at any time in a web page. An XMLHttp request is sent from a script in an html page on my workstation to the server. The Node web server function responds with a JSON structure of results, sent back to the browser (about 250k). The report includes the tick count and the ticks per second stats, which are displayed in the browser. The browser also uses a timer loop to repeat the web page request every 100ms, to get the latest up-to-date information.

It runs smoothly and left to its own devices the cycle count reported on the web page reports around **80 cycles per second**. I was somewhat puzzled that this is quite low, and I thought maybe the frequency of the web page requests was too high. However, the server CPU is not heavily loaded (<3%) and reducing the web page refresh frequency to 1/sec seems to have no effect on the cycle rate. Closing the web browser altogether has no effect either.

Now for the puzzle. If I log in to the server with Remote Desktop, open up VSCode (without opening any source files) move the mouse around on the VSCode window, then *the calculation cycle rate speeds up significantly*. It reliably goes from the background 80 cycles per second to peak at around **500 cycles per second**. When I stop moving the mouse around, the cycle rate drops back to the steady 80 per second. Closing VSCode and moving the mouse around on the server desktop or any other Windows app (notepad, paint, etc) has no effect. It seems that only VSCode that has this impact.

Why is it that increasing the mouse activity in the VSCode window causes my completely separate Node application to speed up significantly?

*Note:* I thought that the activity in VSCode may be slowing down the interval at which the stats are being calculated - so if it was running every 6 secs instead of every second, then it would record a higher rate. However, the stats report is being updated in the web page every second, and the cycles per second changes every second too, so it is definitely being recalculated.

Here is some of the code:

1. The batch calculation cycle:

   // ========================================================================================== T1
   /**

   - This function is triggered on a Timeout timer to run a calculation cycle
     */
     var forestTimeTickCount = 0;
     var ticksPerSecond = 0;
     var prevTickCount = 0;

   function forestTimeTick(){

   ```
    // increment the time tick count
    forestTimeTickCount++;
    if( forestTimeTickCount % 1000 == 0 ) log( "... tick " + forestTimeTickCount ) ;

    // update the plant calculations (batch of 2000)
    plants.timeTick(forestTimeTickCount);

    // if the clock is running, schedule the time for the next clock tick
    if( clockIsRunning ) setTimeout( forestTimeTick, 1 );
   ```

   }

   // calculator for the ticks per second
   function calcTPS(){
   ticksPerSecond = forestTimeTickCount - prevTickCount;
   prevTickCount = forestTimeTickCount;
   }

   // repeat the ticks per second calculation every second
   setInterval( calcTPS, 1000 );
2. This is the Node.http web server creation:

   //create a server object on port MainPort and listen for requests
   try{

   ```
    var MainPortServer = http.createServer( (req, res) =>{

        let dataString = "";
        req.on( "data", chunk => {
            let sChunk = chunk.toString( "utf8" );
            log( "MainPort Chunk: ", sChunk );
            dataString += sChunk;
        });

        req.on( "end", () => {
            let qParams = getAllRequestData( req , dataString );
            handlePortMainPortRequest( req, res, qParams );

        });

    });

    MainPortServer.on("error", err=>{
        console.error( err );
        log( ">>>>>>>>>>>>> TERMINATING")
        process.exit (1);
    });

    MainPortServer.listen( mainPort);
    log( "Web server [MainPort] listening on port " + mainPort )
   ```

   } catch(e) {
   console.error( e );
   log( ">>>>>>>>>>>>> TERMINATING")
   process.exit (1);
   }
3. This is the function that processes the web request:

   function handlePortMainPortRequest (req, res, qParams ) {

   ```
    if( !qParams.path || qParams.path.length == 0 ) { qParams.path = [ "reset" ] };

    switch( qParams.path[0] ){

        // This case handles a request for JSON structure of latest status
        case "pcl":

            // generate the JSON to be sent
            var pcl = plants.getPlantStatusList();

            // add the tick count and ticks per second stats
            pcl.push( { tick: forest.ticks(), tps: forest.tps() } );

            res.setHeader( "Content-type", "application/json" );
            res.end( JSON.stringify( pcl ) );
            return; 

       //
       /// There are other cases here, not relevant to the question
       //

    }
   ```

   }

**Web page clips**

This shows the normal tick rate without MSCode running (tick rate 76/ps):

[image: Tick rate without MSCode running (76tps)]

And this is a snapshot taken while moving the mouse around on MSCode in the server through remote desktop (tick rate 517/s):

[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3744032/why-are-net-timers-limited-to-15-ms-resolution sounds like could be an explanation... (purely based on the fact you use timers and some other app impacting that, I can't really answer it)

Comment: Thanks Alexei but it doesn't seem to provide a reason for why the app is still quite slow when nothing else is running.

Comment: What are you actually doing inside of `plants.timeTick()`?  And, why do you have to do it over and over again as fast as you possibly can?  There seems to me to be something just fundamentally flawed with that design in the first place.  I'm wondering if there isn't a better way to solve your overall problem (which you don't really share so we can't help with).

Comment: The system will be modelling mutation of plant genes in varied environments (warm, humid, cold, hot, windy, dry, steady, variable) over long timescales, although there is still a lot of the model to be built. At the moment there is just simple calculation using a lot of calls to Math.random(). I would be surprised if that has any influence on the stated question (unless, that is, VSCode gives Math.random() a turbo boost). As to "fundamentally flawed", I feel somewhat under unjustified attack . . . .

Answer (score 0):

After a bit of further research, the answer to this question seems to lie in some anomaly in the timer handling, affecting the way in which Node.js interacts with the system timers.

I have transferred the application to a newer server, also Windows Server 2012 but different motherboard/CPU, and repeated the experiment.

On this server, running VSCode has no effect on the performance of the application. AFAIK, the only difference between the servers is that the slower one is a (somewhat aged) Fujitsu Intel XEON running on an AMI motherboard, whereas the faster is a locally-built Intel Core I7 running on an ASRock motherboard. The I7/ASRock combination runs the application around 3-5x faster than the Xeon.

My conjecture is that having VSCode running, and moving the mouse, causes multiple interrupts that cause Windows to short-cut the setTimout function in some way - maybe checking sooner for timer elapse than it would otherwise have done. But it's probably not worth the trouble to research that any further.

Thanks to Alexei Levenkov and JFriend for your comments.