# Precise capture loop

Tags: c#, .net, wait, thread-sleep

## Issue

I'm implementing a capture loop with a FPS/FPM/FPH (seconds, minutes, hours) control. Meaning that the user can capture something normally or as a time-lapse.

Here's my code:

```
private System.Threading.CancellationTokenSource _captureToken;
private List<long> _timeList = new List<long>();

private void CaptureRun(int interval)
{
    var sw = new Stopwatch();
    
    while (_captureToken != null && !_captureToken.IsCancellationRequested)
    {
        sw.Restart();

        //Capture happens here...
        //With or without my capture code, the result is the same (the difference in average time).
        //So I removed this part of the code to make it easier to understand.

        //If behind wait time, wait before capturing again.
        if (sw.ElapsedMilliseconds < interval)
            System.Threading.SpinWait.SpinUntil(() => sw.ElapsedMilliseconds >= interval);

        _timeList.Add(sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);
    }
}


//Code that starts the capture (simplified).
private void StopCapture()
{
    _captureToken = new System.Threading.CancellationTokenSource();

    Task.Run(() => CaptureRun(16), _captureToken.Token);
}


//Code that stops the capture.
private void StopCapture()
{
    if (_captureToken != null)
    {
        _captureToken.Cancel();
        _captureToken.Dispose();
        _captureToken = null;
    }
}
```

The issue being that if the interval is set to 60 FPS (16ms), the resulting capture time averages in 30ms. But if I set the capture interval to 15ms (> 60 FPS), it averages in 15ms as expected.

I wonder why that happens and if it's possible to improve the code.

---

## Solution

Based on Alois' comment, I managed to create this extension class:

```cs
internal class TimerResolution : IDisposable
{
    #region Native

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    private readonly struct TimeCaps
    {
        internal readonly uint MinimumResolution;
        internal readonly uint MaximumResolution;
    };

    internal enum TimerResult : uint
    {
        NoError = 0,
        NoCanDo = 97
    }

    [DllImport("winmm.dll", EntryPoint = "timeGetDevCaps", SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern uint GetDevCaps(ref TimeCaps timeCaps, uint sizeTimeCaps);

    [DllImport("ntdll.dll", EntryPoint = "NtQueryTimerResolution", SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern int QueryTimerResolution(out int maximumResolution, out int minimumResolution, out int currentResolution);

    [DllImport("winmm.dll", EntryPoint = "timeBeginPeriod")]
    internal static extern uint BeginPeriod(uint uMilliseconds);

    [DllImport("winmm.dll", EntryPoint = "timeGetTime")]
    internal static extern uint GetTime();

    [DllImport("winmm.dll", EntryPoint = "timeEndPeriod")]
    internal static extern uint EndPeriod(uint uMilliseconds);

    #endregion

    #region Properties

    /// <summary>
    /// The target resolution in milliseconds.
    /// </summary>
    public uint TargetResolution { get; private set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// The current resolution in milliseconds.
    /// May differ from target resolution based on system limitation.
    /// </summary>
    public uint CurrentResolution { get; private set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// True if a new resolution was set (target resolution or not).
    /// </summary>
    public bool SuccessfullySetResolution { get; private set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// True if a new target resolution was set.
    /// </summary>
    public bool SuccessfullySetTargetResolution { get; private set; }

    #endregion

    /// <summary>
    /// Tries setting a given target timer resolution to the current thread.
    /// If the selected resolution can be set, a nearby value will be set instead.
    /// This must be disposed afterwards (or call EndPeriod() passing the CurrentResolution)
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="targetResolution">The target resolution in milliseconds.</param>
    public TimerResolution(int targetResolution)
    {
        TargetResolution = (uint) targetResolution;

        //Get system limits.
        var timeCaps = new TimeCaps();
        if (GetDevCaps(ref timeCaps, (uint) Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(TimeCaps))) != (uint) TimerResult.NoError)
            return;

        //Calculates resolution based on system limits.
        CurrentResolution = Math.Min(Math.Max(timeCaps.MinimumResolution, TargetResolution), timeCaps.MaximumResolution);

        //Begins the period in which the thread will run on this new timer resolution.
        if (BeginPeriod(CurrentResolution) != (uint) TimerResult.NoError)
            return;

        SuccessfullySetResolution = true;

        if (CurrentResolution == TargetResolution)
            SuccessfullySetTargetResolution = true;
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        if (SuccessfullySetResolution)
            EndPeriod(CurrentResolution);
    }
}
```

Just use the extension class in a `using` block and put it inside whatever you want to run in another timer resolution:

```cs
using (var resolution = new TimerResolution(1))
{
    //...
}
```

Comment: @marsze Precision perhaps.

Comment: Windows doesn’t have precise timers

Comment: Is there something close to precise available?

Comment: Possible dupe: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3744032/why-are-net-timers-limited-to-15-ms-resolution

Comment: You should just do your code in a tight loop and measure. Don’t worry about delaying

Comment: Thanks, I would say that the answer to this question is the question of that thread. Nut it's not a duplicate. Like "Why I'm getting wet when it rains?" and "Why rain is wet?"

Comment: @DanielA.White Isn't that going to remove the framerate control? Btw, is SpinWait any good for longer duration of wait, like minutes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You see a 15 ms delays when sleeping for 15ms and a 30 ms delays when sleeping for 16ms because SpinWait uses under the hood Environment.TickCount which relies on the system clock which has apparently on your system a 15ms resolution.
You can set the system wide timer resolution by using timeBeginPeriod.
See

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/timeapi/nf-timeapi-timebeginperiod

and

- https://randomascii.wordpress.com/2020/10/04/windows-timer-resolution-the-great-rule-change/

for more in depth information about the clock resolution. You can check your current sytem wide timer resolution with clockres from sysinternals.

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/clockres

See example output:

```
C:>clockres

Clockres v2.1 - Clock resolution display utility
Copyright (C) 2016 Mark Russinovich
Sysinternals

Maximum timer interval: 15.625 ms
Minimum timer interval: 0.500 ms
**Current timer interval: 15.625 ms**
```

When a WPF application is running (e.g. Visual Studio)

```
Maximum timer interval: 15.625 ms
Minimum timer interval: 0.500 ms
**Current timer interval: 1.000 ms**
```

then you get a 1ms resolution because every WPF application changes the clock resolution to 1ms. This is also used by some guys as workaround to "fix" the issue.

Comment: Interesting, mine says `Current timer interval: 0.500 ms` already.

Comment: The second link contains changes to the global nature of timer resolution which you might be experiencing now. The safest bet it to call timebeginPeriod in your own application because you cannot rely anymore on other processes to call it for you and be effective for your application as well.

Comment: Thank you. I created an extension class and applied to my code. Everything works nice, I'm able to reach the average 16ms. Just one question, do you think that the `SpinWait` still makes sense in my case?

Comment: @NickeManarin: No. SpinWait/Locks are super special. If you wait longer than 1ms you just waste power. See https://aloiskraus.wordpress.com/2018/06/16/why-skylakex-cpus-are-sometimes-50-slower-how-intel-has-broken-existing-code/ how they are actually done and how subtle they can break.

Comment: Hmmm, but how could I capture something within a given frequency?

Comment: You can use high precision timers, or try a combination of sleep and spinning for the rest of the time. If you are ok with ms you can do a var sw = Stopwatch.StartNew(); while(sw.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds < frequency ) { Thread.Sleep(1) }