# how we can improve the resolution of GetProcessTimes?

Tags: c#, c++, .net, dll, time

I'm using native function to get process Time the function is

```
static extern bool GetProcessTimes(IntPtr hProcess, out FILETIME
       lpCreationTime, out FILETIME lpExitTime, out FILETIME lpKernelTime,
       out FILETIME lpUserTime);
```

But the problem here is that the resolution of the value returned by lpKernelTime,lpUserTime is 15.6ms. mean that we can get ticks 0-156001-320002 all multiple of 156001.

Their is any way to reduce this resolution to 1ms or less like to have value like 0-1000-2000-3000...

Comment: I saw a similar question the other day, the answer was no. not on windows

Comment: So can we do it in other system that is able to run .NET app ?

Comment: I think the consensus was that you need a real time OS in order to _reliably_ achieve ms acuracy

Comment: So Do u know any real Time OS where i can run .NET app ?

Comment: @Ewan: The similar question was asked in "[How we can reduce the resolution of myProcess.TotalProcessorTime?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/29676704/1504523)" and it was asked by _Omega_

Comment: @Ewan Yes still looking for the approach :(